# List of tuples with computed and non-computed values?

Tags: python, list, mapping, tuples, immutability

The first two elements of my `tuple`s are computated (see below), but I want them to be 3-`tuple`s rather than 2-`tuple`s with the last element being set to `1`.

```
from itertools import permutations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    print list(permutations(alphabet,2))
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/jagv6):

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('a', 'g'), ('a', 'h'), ('a', 'i'), ('a', 'j'), ('a', 'k'), ('a', 'l'), ('a', 'm'), ('a', 'n'), ('a', 'o'), ('a', 'p'), ('a', 'q'), ('a', 'r'), ('a', 's'), ('a', 't'), ('a', 'u'), ('a', 'v'), ('a', 'w'), ('a', 'x'), ('a', 'y'), ('a', 'z'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('b', 'g'), ('b', 'h'), ('b', 'i'), ('b', 'j'), ('b', 'k'), ('b', 'l'), ('b', 'm'), ('b', 'n'), ('b', 'o'), ('b', 'p'), ('b', 'q'), ('b', 'r'), ('b', 's'), ('b', 't'), ('b', 'u'), ('b', 'v'), ('b', 'w'), ('b', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('c', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('c', 'h'), ('c', 'i'), ('c', 'j'), ('c', 'k'), ('c', 'l'), ('c', 'm'), ('c', 'n'), ('c', 'o'), ('c', 'p'), ('c', 'q'), ('c', 'r'), ('c', 's'), ('c', 't'), ('c', 'u'), ('c', 'v'), ('c', 'w'), ('c', 'x'), ('c', 'y'), ('c', 'z'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'b'), ('d', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'f'), ('d', 'g'), ('d', 'h'), ('d', 'i'), ('d', 'j'), ('d', 'k'), ('d', 'l'), ('d', 'm'), ('d', 'n'), ('d', 'o'), ('d', 'p'), ('d', 'q'), ('d', 'r'), ('d', 's'), ('d', 't'), ('d', 'u'), ('d', 'v'), ('d', 'w'), ('d', 'x'), ('d', 'y'), ('d', 'z'), ('e', 'a'), ('e', 'b'), ('e', 'c'), ('e', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', 'g'), ('e', 'h'), ('e', 'i'), ('e', 'j'), ('e', 'k'), ('e', 'l'), ('e', 'm'), ('e', 'n'), ('e', 'o'), ('e', 'p'), ('e', 'q'), ('e', 'r'), ('e', 's'), ('e', 't'), ('e', 'u'), ('e', 'v'), ('e', 'w'), ('e', 'x'), ('e', 'y'), ('e', 'z'), ('f', 'a'), ('f', 'b'), ('f', 'c'), ('f', 'd'), ('f', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('f', 'h'), ('f', 'i'), ('f', 'j'), ('f', 'k'), ('f', 'l'), ('f', 'm'), ('f', 'n'), ('f', 'o'), ('f', 'p'), ('f', 'q'), ('f', 'r'), ('f', 's'), ('f', 't'), ('f', 'u'), ('f', 'v'), ('f', 'w'), ('f', 'x'), ('f', 'y'), ('f', 'z'), ('g', 'a'), ('g', 'b'), ('g', 'c'), ('g', 'd'), ('g', 'e'), ('g', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('g', 'i'), ('g', 'j'), ('g', 'k'), ('g', 'l'), ('g', 'm'), ('g', 'n'), ('g', 'o'), ('g', 'p'), ('g', 'q'), ('g', 'r'), ('g', 's'), ('g', 't'), ('g', 'u'), ('g', 'v'), ('g', 'w'), ('g', 'x'), ('g', 'y'), ('g', 'z'), ('h', 'a'), ('h', 'b'), ('h', 'c'), ('h', 'd'), ('h', 'e'), ('h', 'f'), ('h', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('h', 'j'), ('h', 'k'), ('h', 'l'), ('h', 'm'), ('h', 'n'), ('h', 'o'), ('h', 'p'), ('h', 'q'), ('h', 'r'), ('h', 's'), ('h', 't'), ('h', 'u'), ('h', 'v'), ('h', 'w'), ('h', 'x'), ('h', 'y'), ('h', 'z'), ('i', 'a'), ('i', 'b'), ('i', 'c'), ('i', 'd'), ('i', 'e'), ('i', 'f'), ('i', 'g'), ('i', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('i', 'k'), ('i', 'l'), ('i', 'm'), ('i', 'n'), ('i', 'o'), ('i', 'p'), ('i', 'q'), ('i', 'r'), ('i', 's'), ('i', 't'), ('i', 'u'), ('i', 'v'), ('i', 'w'), ('i', 'x'), ('i', 'y'), ('i', 'z'), ('j', 'a'), ('j', 'b'), ('j', 'c'), ('j', 'd'), ('j', 'e'), ('j', 'f'), ('j', 'g'), ('j', 'h'), ('j', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('j', 'l'), ('j', 'm'), ('j', 'n'), ('j', 'o'), ('j', 'p'), ('j', 'q'), ('j', 'r'), ('j', 's'), ('j', 't'), ('j', 'u'), ('j', 'v'), ('j', 'w'), ('j', 'x'), ('j', 'y'), ('j', 'z'), ('k', 'a'), ('k', 'b'), ('k', 'c'), ('k', 'd'), ('k', 'e'), ('k', 'f'), ('k', 'g'), ('k', 'h'), ('k', 'i'), ('k', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('k', 'm'), ('k', 'n'), ('k', 'o'), ('k', 'p'), ('k', 'q'), ('k', 'r'), ('k', 's'), ('k', 't'), ('k', 'u'), ('k', 'v'), ('k', 'w'), ('k', 'x'), ('k', 'y'), ('k', 'z'), ('l', 'a'), ('l', 'b'), ('l', 'c'), ('l', 'd'), ('l', 'e'), ('l', 'f'), ('l', 'g'), ('l', 'h'), ('l', 'i'), ('l', 'j'), ('l', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('l', 'n'), ('l', 'o'), ('l', 'p'), ('l', 'q'), ('l', 'r'), ('l', 's'), ('l', 't'), ('l', 'u'), ('l', 'v'), ('l', 'w'), ('l', 'x'), ('l', 'y'), ('l', 'z'), ('m', 'a'), ('m', 'b'), ('m', 'c'), ('m', 'd'), ('m', 'e'), ('m', 'f'), ('m', 'g'), ('m', 'h'), ('m', 'i'), ('m', 'j'), ('m', 'k'), ('m', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('m', 'o'), ('m', 'p'), ('m', 'q'), ('m', 'r'), ('m', 's'), ('m', 't'), ('m', 'u'), ('m', 'v'), ('m', 'w'), ('m', 'x'), ('m', 'y'), ('m', 'z'), ('n', 'a'), ('n', 'b'), ('n', 'c'), ('n', 'd'), ('n', 'e'), ('n', 'f'), ('n', 'g'), ('n', 'h'), ('n', 'i'), ('n', 'j'), ('n', 'k'), ('n', 'l'), ('n', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('n', 'p'), ('n', 'q'), ('n', 'r'), ('n', 's'), ('n', 't'), ('n', 'u'), ('n', 'v'), ('n', 'w'), ('n', 'x'), ('n', 'y'), ('n', 'z'), ('o', 'a'), ('o', 'b'), ('o', 'c'), ('o', 'd'), ('o', 'e'), ('o', 'f'), ('o', 'g'), ('o', 'h'), ('o', 'i'), ('o', 'j'), ('o', 'k'), ('o', 'l'), ('o', 'm'), ('o', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('o', 'q'), ('o', 'r'), ('o', 's'), ('o', 't'), ('o', 'u'), ('o', 'v'), ('o', 'w'), ('o', 'x'), ('o', 'y'), ('o', 'z'), ('p', 'a'), ('p', 'b'), ('p', 'c'), ('p', 'd'), ('p', 'e'), ('p', 'f'), ('p', 'g'), ('p', 'h'), ('p', 'i'), ('p', 'j'), ('p', 'k'), ('p', 'l'), ('p', 'm'), ('p', 'n'), ('p', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('p', 'r'), ('p', 's'), ('p', 't'), ('p', 'u'), ('p', 'v'), ('p', 'w'), ('p', 'x'), ('p', 'y'), ('p', 'z'), ('q', 'a'), ('q', 'b'), ('q', 'c'), ('q', 'd'), ('q', 'e'), ('q', 'f'), ('q', 'g'), ('q', 'h'), ('q', 'i'), ('q', 'j'), ('q', 'k'), ('q', 'l'), ('q', 'm'), ('q', 'n'), ('q', 'o'), ('q', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('q', 's'), ('q', 't'), ('q', 'u'), ('q', 'v'), ('q', 'w'), ('q', 'x'), ('q', 'y'), ('q', 'z'), ('r', 'a'), ('r', 'b'), ('r', 'c'), ('r', 'd'), ('r', 'e'), ('r', 'f'), ('r', 'g'), ('r', 'h'), ('r', 'i'), ('r', 'j'), ('r', 'k'), ('r', 'l'), ('r', 'm'), ('r', 'n'), ('r', 'o'), ('r', 'p'), ('r', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('r', 't'), ('r', 'u'), ('r', 'v'), ('r', 'w'), ('r', 'x'), ('r', 'y'), ('r', 'z'), ('s', 'a'), ('s', 'b'), ('s', 'c'), ('s', 'd'), ('s', 'e'), ('s', 'f'), ('s', 'g'), ('s', 'h'), ('s', 'i'), ('s', 'j'), ('s', 'k'), ('s', 'l'), ('s', 'm'), ('s', 'n'), ('s', 'o'), ('s', 'p'), ('s', 'q'), ('s', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('s', 'u'), ('s', 'v'), ('s', 'w'), ('s', 'x'), ('s', 'y'), ('s', 'z'), ('t', 'a'), ('t', 'b'), ('t', 'c'), ('t', 'd'), ('t', 'e'), ('t', 'f'), ('t', 'g'), ('t', 'h'), ('t', 'i'), ('t', 'j'), ('t', 'k'), ('t', 'l'), ('t', 'm'), ('t', 'n'), ('t', 'o'), ('t', 'p'), ('t', 'q'), ('t', 'r'), ('t', 's'), ('t', 'u'), ('t', 'v'), ('t', 'w'), ('t', 'x'), ('t', 'y'), ('t', 'z'), ('u', 'a'), ('u', 'b'), ('u', 'c'), ('u', 'd'), ('u', 'e'), ('u', 'f'), ('u', 'g'), ('u', 'h'), ('u', 'i'), ('u', 'j'), ('u', 'k'), ('u', 'l'), ('u', 'm'), ('u', 'n'), ('u', 'o'), ('u', 'p'), ('u', 'q'), ('u', 'r'), ('u', 's'), ('u', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('u', 'w'), ('u', 'x'), ('u', 'y'), ('u', 'z'), ('v', 'a'), ('v', 'b'), ('v', 'c'), ('v', 'd'), ('v', 'e'), ('v', 'f'), ('v', 'g'), ('v', 'h'), ('v', 'i'), ('v', 'j'), ('v', 'k'), ('v', 'l'), ('v', 'm'), ('v', 'n'), ('v', 'o'), ('v', 'p'), ('v', 'q'), ('v', 'r'), ('v', 's'), ('v', 't'), ('v', 'u'), ('v', 'w'), ('v', 'x'), ('v', 'y'), ('v', 'z'), ('w', 'a'), ('w', 'b'), ('w', 'c'), ('w', 'd'), ('w', 'e'), ('w', 'f'), ('w', 'g'), ('w', 'h'), ('w', 'i'), ('w', 'j'), ('w', 'k'), ('w', 'l'), ('w', 'm'), ('w', 'n'), ('w', 'o'), ('w', 'p'), ('w', 'q'), ('w', 'r'), ('w', 's'), ('w', 't'), ('w', 'u'), ('w', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('w', 'y'), ('w', 'z'), ('x', 'a'), ('x', 'b'), ('x', 'c'), ('x', 'd'), ('x', 'e'), ('x', 'f'), ('x', 'g'), ('x', 'h'), ('x', 'i'), ('x', 'j'), ('x', 'k'), ('x', 'l'), ('x', 'm'), ('x', 'n'), ('x', 'o'), ('x', 'p'), ('x', 'q'), ('x', 'r'), ('x', 's'), ('x', 't'), ('x', 'u'), ('x', 'v'), ('x', 'w'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'z'), ('y', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('y', 'c'), ('y', 'd'), ('y', 'e'), ('y', 'f'), ('y', 'g'), ('y', 'h'), ('y', 'i'), ('y', 'j'), ('y', 'k'), ('y', 'l'), ('y', 'm'), ('y', 'n'), ('y', 'o'), ('y', 'p'), ('y', 'q'), ('y', 'r'), ('y', 's'), ('y', 't'), ('y', 'u'), ('y', 'v'), ('y', 'w'), ('y', 'x'), ('y', 'z'), ('z', 'a'), ('z', 'b'), ('z', 'c'), ('z', 'd'), ('z', 'e'), ('z', 'f'), ('z', 'g'), ('z', 'h'), ('z', 'i'), ('z', 'j'), ('z', 'k'), ('z', 'l'), ('z', 'm'), ('z', 'n'), ('z', 'o'), ('z', 'p'), ('z', 'q'), ('z', 'r'), ('z', 's'), ('z', 't'), ('z', 'u'), ('z', 'v'), ('z', 'w'), ('z', 'x'), ('z', 'y')]
```

Trying to efficiently get to this:

```
[('a', 'b', 1), ('a', 'c', 1), ('a', 'd', 1), ('a', 'e', 1), ('a', 'f', 1), ('a', 'g', 1), ('a', 'h', 1), ('a', 'i', 1), ('a', 'j', 1), ('a', 'k', 1), ('a', 'l', 1), ('a', 'm', 1), ('a', 'n', 1), ('a', 'o', 1), ('a', 'p', 1), ('a', 'q', 1), ('a', 'r', 1), ('a', 's', 1), ('a', 't', 1), ('a', 'u', 1), ('a', 'v', 1), ('a', 'w', 1), ('a', 'x', 1), ('a', 'y', 1), ('a', 'z', 1), ('b', 'a', 1), ('b', 'c', 1), ('b', 'd', 1), ('b', 'e', 1), ('b', 'f', 1), ('b', 'g', 1), ('b', 'h', 1), ('b', 'i', 1), ('b', 'j', 1), ('b', 'k', 1), ('b', 'l', 1), ('b', 'm', 1), ('b', 'n', 1), ('b', 'o', 1), ('b', 'p', 1), ('b', 'q', 1), ('b', 'r', 1), ('b', 's', 1), ('b', 't', 1), ('b', 'u', 1), ('b', 'v', 1), ('b', 'w', 1), ('b', 'x', 1), ('b', 'y', 1), ('b', 'z', 1), ('c', 'a', 1), ('c', 'b', 1), ('c', 'd', 1), ('c', 'e', 1), ('c', 'f', 1), ('c', 'g', 1), ('c', 'h', 1), ('c', 'i', 1), ('c', 'j', 1), ('c', 'k', 1), ('c', 'l', 1), ('c', 'm', 1), ('c', 'n', 1), ('c', 'o', 1), ('c', 'p', 1), ('c', 'q', 1), ('c', 'r', 1), ('c', 's', 1), ('c', 't', 1), ('c', 'u', 1), ('c', 'v', 1), ('c', 'w', 1), ('c', 'x', 1), ('c', 'y', 1), ('c', 'z', 1), ('d', 'a', 1), ('d', 'b', 1), ('d', 'c', 1), ('d', 'e', 1), ('d', 'f', 1), ('d', 'g', 1), ('d', 'h', 1), ('d', 'i', 1), ('d', 'j', 1), ('d', 'k', 1), ('d', 'l', 1), ('d', 'm', 1), ('d', 'n', 1), ('d', 'o', 1), ('d', 'p', 1), ('d', 'q', 1), ('d', 'r', 1), ('d', 's', 1), ('d', 't', 1), ('d', 'u', 1), ('d', 'v', 1), ('d', 'w', 1), ('d', 'x', 1), ('d', 'y', 1), ('d', 'z', 1), ('e', 'a', 1), ('e', 'b', 1), ('e', 'c', 1), ('e', 'd', 1), ('e', 'f', 1), ('e', 'g', 1), ('e', 'h', 1), ('e', 'i', 1), ('e', 'j', 1), ('e', 'k', 1), ('e', 'l', 1), ('e', 'm', 1), ('e', 'n', 1), ('e', 'o', 1), ('e', 'p', 1), ('e', 'q', 1), ('e', 'r', 1), ('e', 's', 1), ('e', 't', 1), ('e', 'u', 1), ('e', 'v', 1), ('e', 'w', 1), ('e', 'x', 1), ('e', 'y', 1), ('e', 'z', 1), ('f', 'a', 1), ('f', 'b', 1), ('f', 'c', 1), ('f', 'd', 1), ('f', 'e', 1), ('f', 'g', 1), ('f', 'h', 1), ('f', 'i', 1), ('f', 'j', 1), ('f', 'k', 1), ('f', 'l', 1), ('f', 'm', 1), ('f', 'n', 1), ('f', 'o', 1), ('f', 'p', 1), ('f', 'q', 1), ('f', 'r', 1), ('f', 's', 1), ('f', 't', 1), ('f', 'u', 1), ('f', 'v', 1), ('f', 'w', 1), ('f', 'x', 1), ('f', 'y', 1), ('f', 'z', 1), ('g', 'a', 1), ('g', 'b', 1), ('g', 'c', 1), ('g', 'd', 1), ('g', 'e', 1), ('g', 'f', 1), ('g', 'h', 1), ('g', 'i', 1), ('g', 'j', 1), ('g', 'k', 1), ('g', 'l', 1), ('g', 'm', 1), ('g', 'n', 1), ('g', 'o', 1), ('g', 'p', 1), ('g', 'q', 1), ('g', 'r', 1), ('g', 's', 1), ('g', 't', 1), ('g', 'u', 1), ('g', 'v', 1), ('g', 'w', 1), ('g', 'x', 1), ('g', 'y', 1), ('g', 'z', 1), ('h', 'a', 1), ('h', 'b', 1), ('h', 'c', 1), ('h', 'd', 1), ('h', 'e', 1), ('h', 'f', 1), ('h', 'g', 1), ('h', 'i', 1), ('h', 'j', 1), ('h', 'k', 1), ('h', 'l', 1), ('h', 'm', 1), ('h', 'n', 1), ('h', 'o', 1), ('h', 'p', 1), ('h', 'q', 1), ('h', 'r', 1), ('h', 's', 1), ('h', 't', 1), ('h', 'u', 1), ('h', 'v', 1), ('h', 'w', 1), ('h', 'x', 1), ('h', 'y', 1), ('h', 'z', 1), ('i', 'a', 1), ('i', 'b', 1), ('i', 'c', 1), ('i', 'd', 1), ('i', 'e', 1), ('i', 'f', 1), ('i', 'g', 1), ('i', 'h', 1), ('i', 'j', 1), ('i', 'k', 1), ('i', 'l', 1), ('i', 'm', 1), ('i', 'n', 1), ('i', 'o', 1), ('i', 'p', 1), ('i', 'q', 1), ('i', 'r', 1), ('i', 's', 1), ('i', 't', 1), ('i', 'u', 1), ('i', 'v', 1), ('i', 'w', 1), ('i', 'x', 1), ('i', 'y', 1), ('i', 'z', 1), ('j', 'a', 1), ('j', 'b', 1), ('j', 'c', 1), ('j', 'd', 1), ('j', 'e', 1), ('j', 'f', 1), ('j', 'g', 1), ('j', 'h', 1), ('j', 'i', 1), ('j', 'k', 1), ('j', 'l', 1), ('j', 'm', 1), ('j', 'n', 1), ('j', 'o', 1), ('j', 'p', 1), ('j', 'q', 1), ('j', 'r', 1), ('j', 's', 1), ('j', 't', 1), ('j', 'u', 1), ('j', 'v', 1), ('j', 'w', 1), ('j', 'x', 1), ('j', 'y', 1), ('j', 'z', 1), ('k', 'a', 1), ('k', 'b', 1), ('k', 'c', 1), ('k', 'd', 1), ('k', 'e', 1), ('k', 'f', 1), ('k', 'g', 1), ('k', 'h', 1), ('k', 'i', 1), ('k', 'j', 1), ('k', 'l', 1), ('k', 'm', 1), ('k', 'n', 1), ('k', 'o', 1), ('k', 'p', 1), ('k', 'q', 1), ('k', 'r', 1), ('k', 's', 1), ('k', 't', 1), ('k', 'u', 1), ('k', 'v', 1), ('k', 'w', 1), ('k', 'x', 1), ('k', 'y', 1), ('k', 'z', 1), ('l', 'a', 1), ('l', 'b', 1), ('l', 'c', 1), ('l', 'd', 1), ('l', 'e', 1), ('l', 'f', 1), ('l', 'g', 1), ('l', 'h', 1), ('l', 'i', 1), ('l', 'j', 1), ('l', 'k', 1), ('l', 'm', 1), ('l', 'n', 1), ('l', 'o', 1), ('l', 'p', 1), ('l', 'q', 1), ('l', 'r', 1), ('l', 's', 1), ('l', 't', 1), ('l', 'u', 1), ('l', 'v', 1), ('l', 'w', 1), ('l', 'x', 1), ('l', 'y', 1), ('l', 'z', 1), ('m', 'a', 1), ('m', 'b', 1), ('m', 'c', 1), ('m', 'd', 1), ('m', 'e', 1), ('m', 'f', 1), ('m', 'g', 1), ('m', 'h', 1), ('m', 'i', 1), ('m', 'j', 1), ('m', 'k', 1), ('m', 'l', 1), ('m', 'n', 1), ('m', 'o', 1), ('m', 'p', 1), ('m', 'q', 1), ('m', 'r', 1), ('m', 's', 1), ('m', 't', 1), ('m', 'u', 1), ('m', 'v', 1), ('m', 'w', 1), ('m', 'x', 1), ('m', 'y', 1), ('m', 'z', 1), ('n', 'a', 1), ('n', 'b', 1), ('n', 'c', 1), ('n', 'd', 1), ('n', 'e', 1), ('n', 'f', 1), ('n', 'g', 1), ('n', 'h', 1), ('n', 'i', 1), ('n', 'j', 1), ('n', 'k', 1), ('n', 'l', 1), ('n', 'm', 1), ('n', 'o', 1), ('n', 'p', 1), ('n', 'q', 1), ('n', 'r', 1), ('n', 's', 1), ('n', 't', 1), ('n', 'u', 1), ('n', 'v', 1), ('n', 'w', 1), ('n', 'x', 1), ('n', 'y', 1), ('n', 'z', 1), ('o', 'a', 1), ('o', 'b', 1), ('o', 'c', 1), ('o', 'd', 1), ('o', 'e', 1), ('o', 'f', 1), ('o', 'g', 1), ('o', 'h', 1), ('o', 'i', 1), ('o', 'j', 1), ('o', 'k', 1), ('o', 'l', 1), ('o', 'm', 1), ('o', 'n', 1), ('o', 'p', 1), ('o', 'q', 1), ('o', 'r', 1), ('o', 's', 1), ('o', 't', 1), ('o', 'u', 1), ('o', 'v', 1), ('o', 'w', 1), ('o', 'x', 1), ('o', 'y', 1), ('o', 'z', 1), ('p', 'a', 1), ('p', 'b', 1), ('p', 'c', 1), ('p', 'd', 1), ('p', 'e', 1), ('p', 'f', 1), ('p', 'g', 1), ('p', 'h', 1), ('p', 'i', 1), ('p', 'j', 1), ('p', 'k', 1), ('p', 'l', 1), ('p', 'm', 1), ('p', 'n', 1), ('p', 'o', 1), ('p', 'q', 1), ('p', 'r', 1), ('p', 's', 1), ('p', 't', 1), ('p', 'u', 1), ('p', 'v', 1), ('p', 'w', 1), ('p', 'x', 1), ('p', 'y', 1), ('p', 'z', 1), ('q', 'a', 1), ('q', 'b', 1), ('q', 'c', 1), ('q', 'd', 1), ('q', 'e', 1), ('q', 'f', 1), ('q', 'g', 1), ('q', 'h', 1), ('q', 'i', 1), ('q', 'j', 1), ('q', 'k', 1), ('q', 'l', 1), ('q', 'm', 1), ('q', 'n', 1), ('q', 'o', 1), ('q', 'p', 1), ('q', 'r', 1), ('q', 's', 1), ('q', 't', 1), ('q', 'u', 1), ('q', 'v', 1), ('q', 'w', 1), ('q', 'x', 1), ('q', 'y', 1), ('q', 'z', 1), ('r', 'a', 1), ('r', 'b', 1), ('r', 'c', 1), ('r', 'd', 1), ('r', 'e', 1), ('r', 'f', 1), ('r', 'g', 1), ('r', 'h', 1), ('r', 'i', 1), ('r', 'j', 1), ('r', 'k', 1), ('r', 'l', 1), ('r', 'm', 1), ('r', 'n', 1), ('r', 'o', 1), ('r', 'p', 1), ('r', 'q', 1), ('r', 's', 1), ('r', 't', 1), ('r', 'u', 1), ('r', 'v', 1), ('r', 'w', 1), ('r', 'x', 1), ('r', 'y', 1), ('r', 'z', 1), ('s', 'a', 1), ('s', 'b', 1), ('s', 'c', 1), ('s', 'd', 1), ('s', 'e', 1), ('s', 'f', 1), ('s', 'g', 1), ('s', 'h', 1), ('s', 'i', 1), ('s', 'j', 1), ('s', 'k', 1), ('s', 'l', 1), ('s', 'm', 1), ('s', 'n', 1), ('s', 'o', 1), ('s', 'p', 1), ('s', 'q', 1), ('s', 'r', 1), ('s', 't', 1), ('s', 'u', 1), ('s', 'v', 1), ('s', 'w', 1), ('s', 'x', 1), ('s', 'y', 1), ('s', 'z', 1), ('t', 'a', 1), ('t', 'b', 1), ('t', 'c', 1), ('t', 'd', 1), ('t', 'e', 1), ('t', 'f', 1), ('t', 'g', 1), ('t', 'h', 1), ('t', 'i', 1), ('t', 'j', 1), ('t', 'k', 1), ('t', 'l', 1), ('t', 'm', 1), ('t', 'n', 1), ('t', 'o', 1), ('t', 'p', 1), ('t', 'q', 1), ('t', 'r', 1), ('t', 's', 1), ('t', 'u', 1), ('t', 'v', 1), ('t', 'w', 1), ('t', 'x', 1), ('t', 'y', 1), ('t', 'z', 1), ('u', 'a', 1), ('u', 'b', 1), ('u', 'c', 1), ('u', 'd', 1), ('u', 'e', 1), ('u', 'f', 1), ('u', 'g', 1), ('u', 'h', 1), ('u', 'i', 1), ('u', 'j', 1), ('u', 'k', 1), ('u', 'l', 1), ('u', 'm', 1), ('u', 'n', 1), ('u', 'o', 1), ('u', 'p', 1), ('u', 'q', 1), ('u', 'r', 1), ('u', 's', 1), ('u', 't', 1), ('u', 'v', 1), ('u', 'w', 1), ('u', 'x', 1), ('u', 'y', 1), ('u', 'z', 1), ('v', 'a', 1), ('v', 'b', 1), ('v', 'c', 1), ('v', 'd', 1), ('v', 'e', 1), ('v', 'f', 1), ('v', 'g', 1), ('v', 'h', 1), ('v', 'i', 1), ('v', 'j', 1), ('v', 'k', 1), ('v', 'l', 1), ('v', 'm', 1), ('v', 'n', 1), ('v', 'o', 1), ('v', 'p', 1), ('v', 'q', 1), ('v', 'r', 1), ('v', 's', 1), ('v', 't', 1), ('v', 'u', 1), ('v', 'w', 1), ('v', 'x', 1), ('v', 'y', 1), ('v', 'z', 1), ('w', 'a', 1), ('w', 'b', 1), ('w', 'c', 1), ('w', 'd', 1), ('w', 'e', 1), ('w', 'f', 1), ('w', 'g', 1), ('w', 'h', 1), ('w', 'i', 1), ('w', 'j', 1), ('w', 'k', 1), ('w', 'l', 1), ('w', 'm', 1), ('w', 'n', 1), ('w', 'o', 1), ('w', 'p', 1), ('w', 'q', 1), ('w', 'r', 1), ('w', 's', 1), ('w', 't', 1), ('w', 'u', 1), ('w', 'v', 1), ('w', 'x', 1), ('w', 'y', 1), ('w', 'z', 1), ('x', 'a', 1), ('x', 'b', 1), ('x', 'c', 1), ('x', 'd', 1), ('x', 'e', 1), ('x', 'f', 1), ('x', 'g', 1), ('x', 'h', 1), ('x', 'i', 1), ('x', 'j', 1), ('x', 'k', 1), ('x', 'l', 1), ('x', 'm', 1), ('x', 'n', 1), ('x', 'o', 1), ('x', 'p', 1), ('x', 'q', 1), ('x', 'r', 1), ('x', 's', 1), ('x', 't', 1), ('x', 'u', 1), ('x', 'v', 1), ('x', 'w', 1), ('x', 'y', 1), ('x', 'z', 1), ('y', 'a', 1), ('y', 'b', 1), ('y', 'c', 1), ('y', 'd', 1), ('y', 'e', 1), ('y', 'f', 1), ('y', 'g', 1), ('y', 'h', 1), ('y', 'i', 1), ('y', 'j', 1), ('y', 'k', 1), ('y', 'l', 1), ('y', 'm', 1), ('y', 'n', 1), ('y', 'o', 1), ('y', 'p', 1), ('y', 'q', 1), ('y', 'r', 1), ('y', 's', 1), ('y', 't', 1), ('y', 'u', 1), ('y', 'v', 1), ('y', 'w', 1), ('y', 'x', 1), ('y', 'z', 1), ('z', 'a', 1), ('z', 'b', 1), ('z', 'c', 1), ('z', 'd', 1), ('z', 'e', 1), ('z', 'f', 1), ('z', 'g', 1), ('z', 'h', 1), ('z', 'i', 1), ('z', 'j', 1), ('z', 'k', 1), ('z', 'l', 1), ('z', 'm', 1), ('z', 'n', 1), ('z', 'o', 1), ('z', 'p', 1), ('z', 'q', 1), ('z', 'r', 1), ('z', 's', 1), ('z', 't', 1), ('z', 'u', 1), ('z', 'v', 1), ('z', 'w', 1), ('z', 'x', 1), ('z', 'y', 1)]
```

(I'm happy for it be nested `list` rather than nested 3-`tuple`)

Comment: permutaions of 2 alphas is overkill!

Comment: Wait, just realised I'm not getting the [650 permutations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P(26,2)) I expected. How do I get them?

Comment: Note that making an empty list and appending items in a loop is a really bad sign. For one, you are using list concat where `list.append()` would be better, for a second, this is where a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) would shine).

Comment: append and comprehension gave me a list of list of tuple, whereas += gave it all in one list

Comment: @user1438003 You might want to use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) rather than your own string.

Comment: @user1438003, len(list(permutations(alphabet, 2))) ==> 650

Comment: @user1438003: You just completely changed your question.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10977465/1438003) is still valid

Comment: @user1438003: What do you need the `1` for, by the way?

Comment: Building a frequency distribution table. Not using any of the normal data-structures for this, since my next operation is insertion into a db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution, in case anyone is still interested:

```
[x + (1,) for x in list(permutations(alphabet,2))+[(alpha, alpha) for alpha in alphabet]]
```

Would still be interested if there is a more efficient way of doing this though...

Answer (score 4):

Before `print a`, insert

```
 a = [(x, y, 1) for x, y in a]
```

Or, replace

```
list(permutations([alphabet[i],alphabet[i+1]]))
```

with

```
[(alphabet[i], alphabet[i+1], 1), (alphabet[i+1], alphabet[i], 1)]
```

**EDIT**: with your new requirement, the easiest solution is

```
[(x, y, 1) for x, y in permutations(alphabet, 2)]
```

For general length-*k* permutations, that becomes

```
[p + (1,) for p in permutations(alphabet, k)]
```

Comment: Thanks, [that worked](http://ideone.com/fjoZF). But I am waiting for a solution without post-processing :)

Comment: I have edited my question, I realised something was wrong when I saw you didn't use permutation in your example... can you please see if you can answer this one?

Answer (score 2):

You could change the last line to this:

```
print [x + (1,) for x in a]
```

Comment: Doesn't really solve the spirit of question, does it, altering just the print statement..

Comment: Thanks, rather helpful. [Output](http://ideone.com/r2VWe). Not sure if there's a more efficient solution though...

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over each generated permutation and append the static 1:

```
from itertools import permutations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    a=[]
    for i in xrange(len(alphabet)-1):
        a+=[x + (1,) for x in permutations([alphabet[i],alphabet[i+1]])]
    print a
```

Or, to make this a little more explicit:

```
from itertools import permutations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    a=[]
    for i in xrange(len(alphabet)-1):
        a+=[(l1, l2, 1) for (l1, l2) in permutations([alphabet[i],alphabet[i+1]])]
    print a
```

Both variations produce the desired output and close in efficiency to your `list(generator)` original.